# Create a service as autorun

Tags: windows, go, service, operating-system

**OS:** `windows/7/8/8.1/10 32bit`

I have one question. How to create a service that would work like autorun?
Most applications install themselves in autorun through the `registry` or through `C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. But there are those that are installing through the services, or rather as a service.
I have a code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"
    "syscall"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/mgr"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/debug"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/eventlog"
)

var elog debug.Log

type myservice struct{}

func (m *myservice) Execute(args []string, r <-chan svc.ChangeRequest, changes chan<- svc.Status) (ssec bool, errno uint32) {
    const cmdsAccepted = svc.AcceptStop | svc.AcceptShutdown | svc.AcceptPauseAndContinue
    changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.StartPending}
    fasttick := time.Tick(500 * time.Millisecond)
    slowtick := time.Tick(2 * time.Second)
    tick := fasttick
    changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Running, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
    elog.Info(1, strings.Join(args, "-"))
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case <-tick:
            beep()
            elog.Info(1, "beep")
        case c := <-r:
            switch c.Cmd {
            case svc.Interrogate:
                changes <- c.CurrentStatus
                // Testing deadlock from https://code.google.com/p/winsvc/issues/detail?id=4
                time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
                changes <- c.CurrentStatus
            case svc.Stop, svc.Shutdown:
                break loop
            case svc.Pause:
                changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Paused, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
                tick = slowtick
            case svc.Continue:
                changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Running, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
                tick = fasttick
            default:
                elog.Error(1, fmt.Sprintf("unexpected control request #%d", c))
            }
        }
    }
    changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.StopPending}
    return
}

func runService(name string, isDebug bool) {
    var err error
    if isDebug {
        elog = debug.New(name)
    } else {
        elog, err = eventlog.Open(name)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
    }
    defer elog.Close()

    elog.Info(1, fmt.Sprintf("starting %s service", name))
    run := svc.Run
    if isDebug {
        run = debug.Run
    }
    err = run(name, &myservice{})
    if err != nil {
        elog.Error(1, fmt.Sprintf("%s service failed: %v", name, err))
        return
    }
    elog.Info(1, fmt.Sprintf("%s service stopped", name))
}

func startService(name string) error {
    m, err := mgr.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer m.Disconnect()
    s, err := m.OpenService(name)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not access service: %v", err)
    }
    defer s.Close()
    err = s.Start("is", "auto-started")
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not start service: %v", err)
    }
    return nil
}

func controlService(name string, c svc.Cmd, to svc.State) error {
    m, err := mgr.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer m.Disconnect()
    s, err := m.OpenService(name)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not access service: %v", err)
    }
    defer s.Close()
    status, err := s.Control(c)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not send control=%d: %v", c, err)
    }
    timeout := time.Now().Add(10 * time.Second)
    for status.State != to {
        if timeout.Before(time.Now()) {
            return fmt.Errorf("timeout waiting for service to go to state=%d", to)
        }
        time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond)
        status, err = s.Query()
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("could not retrieve service status: %v", err)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    const svcName = "Best Service"

    isIntSess, err := svc.IsAnInteractiveSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to determine if we are running in an interactive session: %v", err)
    }
    if !isIntSess {
        runService(svcName, false)
        return
    }

    /*err = controlService(svcName, svc.Stop, svc.Stopped)
    err = removeService(svcName)*/
    err = installService(svcName, "Best Service")
    runService(svcName, true)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to %s: %v", svcName, err)
    }
    return
}

func exePath() (string, error) {
    prog := os.Args[0]
    p, err := filepath.Abs(prog)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    fi, err := os.Stat(p)
    if err == nil {
        if !fi.Mode().IsDir() {
            return p, nil
        }
        err = fmt.Errorf("%s is directory", p)
    }
    if filepath.Ext(p) == "" {
        p += ".exe"
        fi, err := os.Stat(p)
        if err == nil {
            if !fi.Mode().IsDir() {
                return p, nil
            }
            err = fmt.Errorf("%s is directory", p)
        }
    }
    return "", err
}

func installService(name, desc string) error {
    exepath, err := exePath()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    m, err := mgr.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer m.Disconnect()
    s, err := m.OpenService(name)
    if err == nil {
        s.Close()
        return fmt.Errorf("service %s already exists", name)
    }
    s, err = m.CreateService(name, exepath, mgr.Config{DisplayName: desc, Description: "BB service"}, "is", "auto-started")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer s.Close()
    err = eventlog.InstallAsEventCreate(name, eventlog.Error|eventlog.Warning|eventlog.Info)
    if err != nil {
        s.Delete()
        return fmt.Errorf("SetupEventLogSource() failed: %s", err)
    }
    return nil
}

func removeService(name string) error {
    m, err := mgr.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer m.Disconnect()
    s, err := m.OpenService(name)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("service %s is not installed", name)
    }
    defer s.Close()
    err = s.Delete()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = eventlog.Remove(name)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("RemoveEventLogSource() failed: %s", err)
    }
    return nil
}

var (
    beepFunc = syscall.MustLoadDLL("user32.dll").MustFindProc("MessageBeep")
)

func beep() {
    beepFunc.Call(0xffffffff)
}
```

Application is installed and every time I exit the application the service stops. I need that even after restarting the PC the service worked and the application started. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

maybe it's not actual but during the creation of the service you should extend and pass Config

> mgr.Config{DisplayName: desc, StartType: mgr.StartAutomatic}

like here:

```
s, err = m.CreateService(name, exepath, mgr.Config{DisplayName: desc, StartType: mgr.StartAutomatic}, "is", "auto-started")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Here you can find all necessary constants and functions:
https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/master/windows/svc/mgr/config.go

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 go to Task Scheduler > Task Scheduler Library > Create Basic Task  > Trigger: when the computer starts > Action: Start a program.

When running the task, use the following user account: SYSTEM.

Comment: Nonono. I need to do this without all the user's actions. And without the rights of the system or so it is impossible?

Comment: Oh, OK.  I see what you want.  It is possible using std lib: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc

Answer (score 0):

There is a package in the standard library that does this:
https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc

example: https://github.com/golang/sys/tree/master/windows/svc/example

Comment: So I used these examples, only combined all the code into one file.